# Spring cloud config server connection to Bitbucket using SSH keys gives No more authentication methods available error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssh, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to create a spring cloud config server to connect to git repository(bitbucket) using an SSH URI. I am following Spring Cloud Config.

I generated key pair using the command

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "sweta"
```

I tried to run below command for known_hosts file

```
ssh webprod-cvs2.test.com
```

Below is the outcome of above command

```
The authenticity of host 'webprod-cvs2.test.com (161.134.126.61)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:rOc67c4dj1nBlEnNJvB5e6u2TkcJo8k7X1VJCWk.
This key is not known by any other names
```

Below is the entry in known_hosts file

```
webprod-cvs2.test.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBOJeugo5WQ2UlUBDH7UWJUOSCp0f20thcUw8G8ZoKP54OBIgsBXeb8x5PxTq86jOmY+K4yYQFHGVdH8Vmz6HsgM=
```

Below is application.properties file

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=git@webprod-cvs2.test.com:7999/micro/config-properties.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignoreLocalSshSettings=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.strictHostKeyChecking=false
spring.cloud.config.server.git.host-key=AAAAE2VjZHNhLXAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBOJeugo5WQ2UlUBDH7UWJUOSCp0f20thcUw8G8ZoKP54OBIgsBXeb8x5PxTq86jOmY+K4yYQFHGVdH8Vmz6HsgM=
spring.cloud.config.server.git.hostKeyAlgorithm=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
spring.cloud.config.server.git.passphrase=secret123
spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED\n\
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,327F2601F22244F902A89CF70200FDE2\n\
\n\
O0SRZZ7qiC0fp6eNGahkd50MQHV0Li3S4wzqbIDsncDpSlp8WJ3wMFAKPDRV++0a\
N54jjVaDzPUVJkDJJvZpX6q5KT8sv54q7EzD8IX5DSnvrRaw8iR12GJF0MC77mCA\
nK3R9FE/iNa/Sg/Ui3woyEfyDR4ocgGYzQHCTdfPgBcV4SihU3503MLEa9yhCoCP\
mbfyEXI6NpfsbZ5ETY8Qek6r5E5XECw8HoU63x858St9Oti1/y36a6kj9cmX/iD7\
I50txX9mW+C/126NoHjYUzb4o5iGxtfB6vP/McBhcw9aEuFYcTJyTepM/nK1IlbL\
y8hQkoEiIz9Ijja6wYkP/0s/6DBhJPTpTMlijyd0yS+xGmCvJLmiqricZHbDAGwr\
L8Xgdp6as3VDgDCR5wQ+jzhFAEt7qToZt3oqD/XeWw0UTYlx5DnvNZGlVWSlvvPe\
7nH1ZqY2S5O6RpPgxsrj/x8nELYGGRp7kftcV28Fu3mlpOGwB2nXQK0uB6JsFKGh\
DEfCKtUZ2L1gEc+R3rNeq3Nji3ZlYzTbEdptuqXr7nQGX/7n5yRL90rNwUuDjv5Z\
HnX/ul5c8kwRbUz5/ZLviJ6gl5KFG8xUJErNcajFTdUaxlqN0plUUtP5X7Bld2M7\
zjv5C3KhOWp6mle82WB09ur1lZPFufhDRXedUm83rtOiWN5gG79EzzgOtybO1R0e\
OTId2A45EdNvnk2f2lHs5c/SQk8Q7VVE2/CHGyIPDnyWH1tiI6+V0Bjcl64kzxnP\
5RhWZ4gJGhS3mLLw3sRzwN5I/16VGc6yJ5qsoAMOYm5Nq4PVk51iKw1lI5NGDvLm\
YYLocfAnsT7L1ro+QfGYKHFWQXMbmxPtyHgWle60er08OufllilXotNjZ47b1xUn\
+XzJzQCmjoVsRjq3wjWiYOyLkR6UXsSJ86F8rYEXkHJ83ZXxPD+8pVm8py2C0/79\
GuWhlkYV6FJPJHXgw3JIp7S7LsyiEftJMFbADpk4KEghKb3oeDKMGkQ5xwCMhoY/\
+NfEWCK6EE9h9Nz2Fzyp3xl/C4ZHd6HtciqNpvrEZZP0BpNbt6EnAItvCdoAKAsh\
lD5Tmh/EdWjrPo29CYV2AvE1KXoa8HWojbiWIv+1SPrBPsfVz0B3hSIihkTmBS2C\
vWZfthHh568UO3kPoRPD0KD8wBrFf433xbzoUxLsTcZadgLqVmhngKmeMtWDdcRt\
bnae/QQQB0GyPaT+EUtJilWPqwFVaBK1qf0fhkRrC8YFcATQP+PyGkQg0CqfCXqS\
CnPjnQQMz+X/K7u952YJTb+CDRaZfD8X5ARZQhJN2yDvr+tEY+DE6A1Jn6QDyM4m\
gcgeIPoWFs237uRvzZ8cNazd6FUgz4inmEVyhkIVE91hUJU3nFeuNggxN8pSEz5j\
z1zTKSCfmCwUOPI6rnbTJKn0UtwLY7TaTFKZQYIOG5rgBGg4y5Qu3hDlvScDt6LS\
ISV0Deve8XqgZtr5hgJrUMsHX4ebzmnoJjRVEA8Ye1cINbJ9EaJ1Q1sjeXD6K+Lb\
I5COg+H7NvZ8+UPrDforLOMxjQUXB0Ri+RRgES7WpKPxzHaYjPM7ynSZn+uw66zT\
h9xNcnkj+MknDQeeTccIHjl7KQuLstfsYJe9TF4AjPdRUEtf5O9OItD/maEhYAvD\
dLgmNMzgVnkrS6bx9RRF4njA/OSTOEu/9YGEfX5qH0ggAOh3BB+jzvwZdKKHHeeO\
yqav4GaCYSbLrUoJeSDyF04QiU7q/kr2/bMDNm1ZP+E1nCORZST0bA71oYOCyCZK\
ck6QrvePe0hRRReHJN6dSeLs8JdmgWzmsbUugb4cZykjBaFro7ZJCitxZuBpj7Iv\
GdXlCYgUxZ4P+O5b0/LJPdSRuAgQDUd4rvX5PHs1E+AU3qyyFhjnQGb3c5rDJSCR\
ty24xkuubD8CLUlP4YPwDK6NS6ywJnSSAFKvneZifo0O50rYqY90PiVyRZclArwM\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Below is the error log:

```
Caused by: org.apache.sshd.common.SshException: No more authentication methods available
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService.tryNext(ClientUserAuthService.java:353) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService.processUserAuth(ClientUserAuthService.java:288) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientUserAuthService.process(ClientUserAuthService.java:225) ~[sshd-osgi-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
```

Can someone please guide me what am I missing?